# Kerberos Auth not working with JDK 11 Oracle 11G & ojdbc8 19.7.0.0

Tags: oracle11g, kerberos, java-11, ojdbc, oracle19c

We use *Oracle 11g* as our RDBMS & were using **Kerberos** Authentication & successfully connected using *JDK8 (v1.8.0.192b31)* & *ojdbc6 (v11.2.0.4)*.

Later we upgraded to *JDK11 (v11.0.7)* and *ojdbc8 (v19.7.0.0)* [did this for **future DB upgrade to Oracle 19c**], but now we are unable to connect using Kerberos & get below error:

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Oracle error ORA-12631
```

Tested it with username/password Auth & it works fine.

Also it works for this combination:
`*JDK 11, Oracle 11g* & *ojdbc6 12.1.2.0*`.

So the question is:

> Which combination of Java & ojdbc can be used to connect to both
> Oracle 11g & 19c using **Kerberos**?

Answer (score 1):

There was an Oracle bug (31716873) that was filed for this issue. The bug fix is currently present in the development branch and will soon be made public. In the meantime if you can stick to JDK8 then the problem should go away. Alternatively you can disable the forwardable ticket option in the Kerberos Config and that should also resolve the problem.

Comment: @Jean-de-laverene Edited the question, added another scenario where it works with JDK 11 & ojdbc6. Is it really a Java 11 issue?

Comment: It's a Java 11 issue with the 19c driver. That's because the 19c code for Kerberos was changed significantly.

Comment: Can you please share a link to this issue or some documentation related to this? Also is there any proposed release date for the fix?

Comment: There is a support issue. So if you have Oracle support you can then use the bug 31716873. The fix will be included in the 21c database release. But again an easy workaround is to disable forwardable tickets which are only used for DBLinks.